# Conditional JSON output for ActiveRecord Model (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ActiveRecord's `as_json` integration with ActiveSupport::JSON to render custom output in my controllers. A basic setup I have in my model looks something like this:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  { :guid  => id,
    :title => title,
    :body  => body,
    :date  => created_at }
end
```

I want to take this setup a step further and show select information depending upon options passed. My question is, when I call `respond_with @model_instance` or `render :json => @model_instance` am I able to pass options that the `options` argument in `as_json` receives? If not, should I just create and convert a unique hash in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could just call `.as_json` and pass in the options, no?

```
render :json => @mymodel.as_json(:someoption =>" value")
```